# Insert of elements in a form using ASP and save into a DB

Tags: html, asp.net

I create this richiesta.html:

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<table border> //create a simple table
<tr>
<td>
<form  ACTION="richiesta.asp"> //open the file richiesta.asp
<table> //start a table format
<tr><td><input name="cognome" size="20"/></tr> //contain a input text 
</table>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
<td><input type="submit" value="Invia"></td><td> // contein a button to send value to DB
</table>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I create richiesta.asp:

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<%
cognome = Request.Form("cognome")
%>
<%
Session.timeout = 1 //Check the session
If IsObject(Session("iscrizioni")) Then
Set conn = Session("iscrizioni")
Else
Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") //Check the connection
conn.open "iscrizioni"
Set Session("iscrizioni") = conn
End If
%>
<% 
If Stato = "" Then 
SQL="INSERT INTO iscrizioni (Cognome) VALUES ("SQL=SQL & "'" & cognome & "', "SQL=SQL ")
response.write(SQL) //
conn.execute(SQL) // Insert value
conn.close  //Close the connection
%>
```

//
  // End Page
 I want to insert in the BD Anagrafica, table Anagrafica the name of a student.
DB structure:
[image]

Comment: place the submit button inside your form :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML Form `action` should be a valid (relative/absolute) url and `not a physical location`.

Also the input control and submit button should be inside form for default form submit.

Please change your `<form>` tags action attribute

```
<form action="riciesta.asp" >

 <table>
  <tr><td><input name="cognome" size="20"/></td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="submit" value="submit"/></td></tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: I try your solution on monday. Thamks for your availability :-)